# How to run custom code before database connection establish in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in my source code I need to set some properties, Database connection certifications on code level before the database connection establishes.

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keystorePassword);
```

edit - I tried it using java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourPassword on runtime, but I want to do it in code level.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you set this with a -D parameter when starting the JVM like in

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourPassword ...
```

This goes along with the [12-factor-apps](https://www.12factor.net/config) and makes your app easier to maintain

Comment: That works, but my requirement is to do that in code level.

Comment: You could perhaps use `@PostContruct` within your `@Config` class like described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations). But then you should not create a connection before the initialization is finished. Or when using spring boot you can do this in the main method of your app before starting Spring Boot. **My advise** would be to refactor the app so that it *can* work with System Properties from the environment

Comment: Really appreciate your help. In my project I do not use any configuration class for connecting to the db. I used persistent entity and spring repositories. I wrote and @postconstruct method in my persistent entity. but it did not work.

Comment: How do you start your application? You should be able to do something *before* you init the spring context.

Comment: currently I set them in main method before SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args); and It works perfectly. Im looking for a better way. and setting them through application properties.

Comment: But when you set the properties already before init the spring context in the main method what is preventing you from putting them in the environment and pass it in as JVM properties?

Comment: the issue is main method is static so I cannot refer Environment.getProperty and I also tried ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = 
           SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
String str = ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("some.prop");
System.out.println("=>>>> " + str);  there also it runs after applcation starts. :/

Comment: If you wish to do it via properties/yml file, create @Configuration class, and you can order them yourself [@AutoConfigureAfter()]